# What was Wittgenstein's view on happiness?

Tags: wittgenstein, happiness

I was wondering whether Wittgenstein is a proponent of happiness being central to a life well lived. Generally, from [Ronald Suter's article](https://doi.org/10.5840/ipq198929315) and what I've read about him, Id wager the answer is yes. However, I found the quote of him saying:

> "I don't know why we are here, but I'm pretty sure that it is not in
> order to enjoy ourselves"

So I was just wondering if anyone well acquainted with him has a better insight

> *"ACCORDING TO WITTGENSTEIN, the worthwhile life is one that is lived happily. He feels such a life needs no justification, for it is
> justified in itself. He says, "I keep on coming back to this! simply
> the happy life is good, the unhappy bad. And if I now ask myself: But
> why should I live happily, then this of itself seems to me to be a
> tautological question; the happy life seems to be justified, of
> itself, it seems that it is the only right life."2 This is why he
> issues the imperative, "Live happily!"